# No visible binding for '<<-' Assignment

Tags: r, package

I have solved variants of the "no visible binding" notes that one gets when checking their package. However, I am unable to solve the situation when applied to the '<<-' assignment.

Specifically, I had defined and used a local variable in several functions, such as:

```
fName = function(df){
  eval({vName<<-0}, envir=environment(fName))
}
```

However when I run check() from devtools, I get the error:

```
fName: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to 'vName'
```

So, I tried using a different syntax, as follows:

```
fName = function(df){
  assign("vName",0, envir=environment(fName))
}
```

But got the check() error:

```
cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

When I tried:

```
fName = function(df){
  assign("vName",0, envir=environment(-1))
}
```

I got the error:

```
use of NULL environment is defunct
```

So, my question is how I can accomplish the assignment operator <<- without getting a note in the check() from devtools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The easy answer is - Don't use `<<-` in your package.  One Alterna way you can make assignments to an environment (but not a meaningful one) is to create a locked binding.

```
e <- new.env()
e$vName <- 0L
lockBinding("vName", e)
vName
# Error: object 'vName' not found
with(e, vName)
# [1] 0
e$vName <- 5
# Error in e$vName <- 5 : cannot change value of locked binding for 'vName'
```

You can also lock an environment, but not a meaningful one.

```
lockEnvironment(e)
rm(vName, envir = e)
# Error in rm(vName, envir = e) : 
#   cannot remove bindings from a locked environment
```

Have a look at `help(bindenv)`, it's a good read.

**Updated** Since you mentioned you might be waiting to make assignment rather than at load  times, have a read of `help(globalVariables)`  It's another best-seller at `?`

> For `globalVariables`, the names supplied are of functions or other objects that should be regarded as defined globally when the check tool is applied to this package. The call to globalVariables will be included in the package's source. Repeated calls in the same package accumulate the names of the global variables.

Comment: `help(bindenv)` "It's a thrilling tale of variables locked away in hostile environments until they are forcefully removed by the hero" says the Washington Post. Four stars out of five.

Comment: Just one step behind my personal favorite, `help(local)`. Four years and i still can't make it work, haha

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think the idea from your first block of code would work, because I do need to alter the variable in the function, and it looks like the value could not be changed from 0 to 5. If this is the only NOTE (sorry I called it an ERROR earlier) I get when I run check(), should I just try to submit it to CRAN as is?

Comment: So let me clarify.  You want to assign a function.  And then later you want to assign a variable to the function, but from outside the function.  Then you wan to be able to change it again later?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if it helps after that many years.I had the same problem,and what i did to solve it is :
`utils::globalVariables(c("global_var"))`

Write this r code somewhere inside the R directory(save it as R file).Whenever you assign a global var assign it also locally like so:

```
global_var<<-1
global_var<-1
```

That worked for me.

Comment: worked for me as well. But it does not work in case of package. `R CMD check` still shows warning against use of "<<-"

Comment: Indeed, as for packages it is recommended not to use it. In case you want to send your work for publication in CRAN they won't accept it unless you get rid of all the "<<-" operators.

Comment: This chapter from [writing R package](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-data-state) helped and is recommended way to handle global variable variables.